# How do I send a Tabcontroller from the homepage to the content page on flutter?

Tags: flutter, controller

How do I send a Tabcontroller from the homepage to the content page ?

I have a home page and implemented a content page with the tab content. The question is how to share or send the controller created on the home page to the tab on the second page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use navigator to pass tab controller

code snippet

```
Navigator.push(context,  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage(tabController: tabController,)));
...
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final TabController tabController;

  // In the constructor, require a Person
  SecondPage({Key key, @required this.tabController}) : super(key: key);
```

In second page, use `widget.tabController`

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  int _counter = 0;
  TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    tabController = new TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage(tabController: tabController,)));
              },
              child: Text(
                  'Second Page',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final TabController tabController;

  // In the constructor, require a Person
  SecondPage({Key key, @required this.tabController}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("GrubX"),
        bottom: TabBar(
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
          labelColor: Colors.amber,
          tabs: [
            new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.call)),
            new Tab(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.chat),
            ),
            new Tab(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.notifications),
            )
          ],
          controller: widget.tabController,
          indicatorColor: Colors.white,
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,),
        bottomOpacity: 1,
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          new Text("This is call Tab View"),
          new Text("This is chat Tab View"),
          new Text("This is notification Tab View"),
        ],
        controller: widget.tabController,),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to help, please mark this as answer if it help you, thanks.